# Perl: Sendmail mails are often not received

Tags: perl, email, sendmail

I use the following function to send e-mails to users registered on my website. The majority of these users receives the mails, however a significant share of them does not recive them, and also cannot find them in their SPAM folder. Could anybody tell me, how I could change the configuration so that everybody could receive the mails?

```
sub pemo_send_email {
    my $recipient = shift, my $subject = shift, my $sender = shift, my $cc = shift,
    my $content = shift;

    open MAIL, "| /usr/lib/sendmail -t -i";
    print MAIL "From: $sender\n";
    print MAIL "To: $recipient\n";
    print MAIL "C" . "c: $cc\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
    print MAIL "Reply-To: $sender\n";
    print MAIL "\n";
    print MAIL "$content";
    close MAIL;
}
```

Comment: Are you sanitizing your user input before putting it into the emails? Any newlines would mess things up, for example.

Comment: More readable: `my ($recipient, $subject, $sender, $cc, $content) = @_;`

Comment: What does you outgoing mail log say? What do your recipients' incoming mail logs say?

Comment: You're not checking that the open succeeded.  Consider using [autodie](http://metacpan.org/pod/autodie).

Answer (score 1):

There may be bugs in your code, and you should consider using a module like [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) instead of rolling your own.  Your mail may also be tossed as spam.  Yes, even if it's not in your users' spam folders.

In this day of rampant spam and phishing, it's not a good idea to send your own mail.  It's just too likely to trip anti-spam protections.  These protections will be at at user's ISP or mail provider and the mail will never reach the user's mail client.

Residential internet accounts, dynamic IPs, VPNs, etc... are often blacklisted.  There are many, many blacklists.  [You can check what lists your IP is on](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check).

It could be failing other anti-spam heuristics. Many of these have to do with what's in the headers, not the body.  [Getting this right is hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#Automated_techniques_for_email_administrators).  A simple one is email `From` a different domain than the server.

My suggestion would be to try sending email via a provider like [GMail](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server) or [pobox.com](http://www.pobox.com/helpspot/index.php?pg=kb.printer.friendly&id=18#p123).  If you're going to be sending a lot of mail, you'll probably have to pay for an outgoing mail service.

Answer (score 0):

If it works sometimes, and not all the time - odds are it's not something fundamentally wrong with your code. It's hard to say for sure, but what you have there *looks* ok.

I'd therefore be starting to thinking two possible sources of problems:

- bad inputs/processing. my personal 'gotcha' is that `"someuser@somewhere.com"` may be interpolated as an array name. But linefeeds are another source of potential error.
- Your mail infrastructure is suffering, maybe mail spool is filling something like that. Check MTA logs and see if anything obvious occurs there. (You don't seem to be checking for a successful `open` of your sendmail, for example)

Oh, and generally I'd suggest 3 arg open is 'good form', e.g:

```
open ( my $mailer, "|-", "/usr/lib/sendmail -t -i" ) or die $!;
print {$mailer} "From: $sender\n";
```

etc.